# Drawing static Line on Pyqt Widget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm not a programmer but i'd like to programming using pyqt that can apply for some engineering application.
So, I want to have a widget that include the graphic (as attached picture) and some other widget such as: textbox, button, etc for user to input or select but I can not figure out which widget or class to make it.

Could you have any advise for this case (drawing using qt designer or code directly is ok)

[image: ui image]

Comment: Do you have image files for the lines?  Is it the arrows that you want to draw?  Is the problem that the length of the lines needs to change (ie. it depends on the GUI window size, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can display pictures with `QLabel`'s

```
label = QtGui.QLabel()
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('/path/to/image.png')
label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: It seem hard to mix Qpixmap with other widget like textbox, etc on the same parent widget, see my case in the link [link] (http://imgur.com/Rdg7xbd). So, could you have other advise?